# Fast Travel glitch in fallout 4

Tags: fallout-4

I joined the BOS and took out the Institute, but after I teleported onto the roof of Mass Fusion,I blew it up but afterwards I couldn't fast travel. It said " You cannot fast travel from the location." Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't fast travel from that location; complete the quest and leave the area in another way.

Comment: I jumped off and have gone back and exited though the building, even after leaving the main city area and going to sanctuary I still can't. The quest is even in the completed category.